# Traverse all directories / sub-directories and fetch permissions of files and folders

Tags: perl, directory

Below is the code snippet to Traverse all directories / sub-directories and fetch permissions of files and folders
Requirement is to fecth file, folders and check if others have w permissions.
i have managed to write part of the code and i am struck at an error and i dont see any uninitialized value .

Below is the error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $retMode in bitwise and (&) at myTest.pl line 24.
```

Code snippet :

```
        use warnings;
        use strict;
        use Data::Dumper;
        use File::stat;
        
        my @dirs = ("/home/mytest");
        my %seen;
        while (my $pwd = shift @dirs) {
                opendir(DIR,"$pwd") or die "Cannot open $pwd\n";
                my @files = readdir(DIR);
                closedir(DIR);
                foreach my $file (@files) {
                        next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
                        my $path = "$pwd/$file";
                        if (-d $path) {
                                next if $seen{$path};
                                $seen{$path} = 1;
                                print "$path \n";
                                push @dirs, $path;
                        }
                        my $info    = stat($path);
                        my $retMode = $info->mode if (defined $info);
                        $retMode = $retMode & 0777;
                        print "$path : $retMode \n";
                        if ($retMode & 002) {
                            # Code comes here if World has write permission on the file
                        }     
                        if ($retMode & 020) {
                            # Code comes here if Group has write permission on the file
                        }

                        #print Dumper \@dirs;
                        # Check for the directory permissions after files
                }
        }
```

~

OUTPUT:

```
        /home/mytest/.vimBU
        /home/mytest/.vimBU : 488
        /home/mytest/.git
        /home/mytest/.git : 488
        /home/mytest/.profile : 416
        Use of uninitialized value $retMode in bitwise and (&) at myTest.pl line 24.
        /home/mytest/.vim : 0
        /home/mytest/.sh_history : 384
        /home/mytest/.bash_history : 384
```

> Is tis the right approach , am trying to get FOLDER PERMISSIONS after the file permissions

Comment: Add `or die $!` after `my $info = stat($path)` and tell us what it outputs.

Comment: I'd use `File::Find` instead.

Comment: does file:find doesnt throw for permissions

Answer (score 0):

some directories you have no permission or relative to runtime process. It's changes after readdir();
add one more line before line 24 and you will see.

```
print "No Permission $path\n" and next if not defined $retMode ;
```